# Como faço pra pular o bloco "finally", em C#, quando a exceção for gerada?

Tags: c#, exceção, try-catch, goto

Caso a exceção seja gerada, quero saber se há uma forma de "pular" a execução do bloco `finally`. Caso não haja exceção, o `finally` execute normalmente.
Com o `goto` não funcionou.

Código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Calculadora
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double n1, n2, multiplicacao;
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Digite o primeiro numero.\n");
                n1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Digite o segundo numero.\n");
                n2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                multiplicacao = n1 * n2;

                Console.WriteLine("\nResultado...\n");
                Console.WriteLine(n1+" * "+n2+" = " + multiplicacao);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Erro ao tentar fazer a conta.");
                goto pular;
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nO finally foi executado...");
            }
            pular:
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n O finally nao foi executou.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não faz muito sentindo isso q vc quer. O `finally` é para garantir que a rotina dentro dele seja sempre executada caso haja uma exceção e esta exceção pare o fluxo e faça com que ele saia do método onde ocorreu a exceção impedindo que um código importante seja executado. Com o `finally` vc consegue dar garantias que seja executado. Se vc ñ quer executar o q esta nele, simplesmente não declare o bloco `finally` e coloque sua rotina abaixo do `catch` para que ela seja executada (sem garantias) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Citando a [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally)

> Normalmente, as instruções de um bloco `finally` são executadas quando o
>   controle deixa uma instrução `try`. A transferência de controle pode
>   ocorrer como resultado da execução normal, da execução de uma
>   instrução `break`, `continue`, `goto` ou `return`, ou da propagação de uma
>   exceção para fora da instrução `try`.
>
> Dentro de uma exceção tratada, é garantido que o bloco `finally` será executado.

Você pode utilizar o método [`Environment.FailFast()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms131100.aspx) para finalizar a aplicação imediatamente, fazendo com que o bloco `finally` não seja executado.

Entretanto, pular o bloco `finally` e executar o código da maneira como você quer não é possível.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Tô tentando implementar no meu código, mas não estou conseguindo. Há como me você dá esse suporte ?

Comment: @RodrigoOliveira utilize `Environment.FailFast("Um erro fatal ocorreu.");`. Lembre de colocar `using System;` no início

Comment: Tô implementando, mas aí está executando o finally. Vamos no chat pra eu te mostrar.

Comment: @RodrigoOliveira colocou dentro do bloco `catch`?

Comment: Sim. Dá uma olhada.    `catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Erro ao tentar fazer a conta.");
                Environment.FailFast(causeOfFailure);`

Comment: Se você não está querendo exeecutar o finally, então porque não tirar o código de dentro dele (que aparentemente seria alguma disposição dos recursos), e colocar depois do try...catch. Nesse caso se não quisesse continuar a aplicação, derrubaria ela no catch. Aliás, pela documentação o goto não pode pular o finally: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664758(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 6):

Não faz nenhum sentido isso que você está querendo, o finally, é para você executar as lógicas necessárias caso o bloco `try` consiga ou não fazer a sua tarefa.

Por exemplo

Você abre a conexão com SQL e depois durante uma consulta a conexão cai será gerado uma exceção, mas dando certo ou erro você precisa fechar a conexão com o SQL, ai você coloca esta lógica no `finally`.

Se você quer pular o finally simplesmente remove-o.

Comment: Eu sei que não faz sentido.Isso é só um demonstrativo pra outra necessidade. É que tenho que usar uma logica parecida em outra implementação, na faculdade. Pois isso coloquei esse  exemplo simples.

Comment: Obrigado. Amigão, acho que a minha pergunta que foi equivocada. Quero que a aplicação seja finalizada, assim ela não executará o finally.

Answer (score 6):

Este código tem vários problemas, alguns são erros, outros é só questão de estilo ruim:

1 - Este problema não precisa lidar com exceção. Ele precisa verificar o erro e dar o devido tratamento. Use [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__) e seja feliz sem exceções.

2 - Se fosse usar exceção, coloque no `Finally` só o que deve ser executado sempre. O que não deve ser executado se gerar uma exceção, coloque fora.

3 - Se capturar uma exceção, faça com a mais específica possível, sói use `Exception` se tiver uma ótima justificativa.

4 - Se não vai usar a variável de exceção, não a use.

5 - Só declare a variável onde vai usá-la, não faça pré-declarações que não trazem benefícios.

6 - Não é o fim do mundo neste caso, mas evite concatenações de *string* e prefira interpolação de *string*.

7 - Fiz outras melhorias quase cosméticas.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace Calculadora {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            WriteLine("Digite o primeiro numero.");
            if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var n1)) { //dá para fazer genérico
                WriteLine("Dado digitado inválido");
                return;
            }
            WriteLine("Digite o segundo numero.");
            if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var n2)) { //reaproveite e não é necessário
                WriteLine("Dado digitado inválido");
                return;
            }
            double multiplicacao = n1 * n2;
            WriteLine("Resultado...");
            WriteLine($"{n1} * {n2} = {multiplicacao}");
            WriteLine("Tudo foi executado...");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WAnb6X). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KQKYKh). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/TryPattern.cs).

Este código exige C# 7, mas com um pequena modificação pode rodar em C# 6 e com pouca coisa mais pode rodar em todas versões.

Se ainda quiser insistir na exceção e até para responder a pergunta, o que você deseja não é pular o `finally` é não existir o `finally`. O mecanismo de finalização da tentativa é que o código deve ser executado em qualquer caso. Se deseja que ele seja pulado quando der a exceção, então ele deve ficar fora de todo o bloco `try-catch-finally`. Simples assim. Pode fazer:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace Calculadora {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
                WriteLine("Digite o primeiro numero.");
                double n1 = double.Parse(ReadLine());
                WriteLine("Digite o segundo numero.");
                double n2 = double.Parse(ReadLine());
                double multiplicacao = n1 * n2;
                WriteLine("Resultado...");
                WriteLine($"{n1} * {n2} = {multiplicacao}");
            } catch (Exception) { //só para efeitos de teste, caso contrário não capture Exception
                WriteLine("Erro ao tentar fazer a conta."); //na prática agora nunca acontecerá a exceção
                WriteLine("O finally nao foi executou.");
                return;
            }
            WriteLine("Tudo foi executado...");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4E3dG9). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/73H4lg). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/AvoidFinally.cs).

Note que há uma outra exceção ocorrendo. Acho que é algo momentâneo no .NET Fiddle, de qualquer forma mostra como é problemático capturar `Exception`, pega o que não se espera.

Reforço que tudo isto está errado, fique com o primeiro.

Se quiser terminar um programa e ele não está no `Main()` então no lugar do `return` deve usar o [`Environment.Exit()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Environment_Exit_System_Int32_), a não ser que esteja em uma aplicação WinForms, aí deve usar o [`Application.Exit()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Application_Exit). Existe outras variações para aplicações de outras tecnologias (WPF, UWP, ASPNET, etc.), inclusive se for um teste. Tem casos que até outras soluções são mais adequadas.

Além do que a pergunta não fala em terminar logo a aplicação, fala em pular o `catch`.

Answer (score 5):

O objetivo do bloco ***finally*** é ser executado tanto após a execução do bloco ***try***, quando após qualquer bloco ***catch***. Não há como "pulá-lo".

Quando iniciamos algum processo no bloco ***try***, que precisa ser encerrado, tais como conexão com o banco ou abertura de um arquivo, normalmente usamos o bloco ***finally*** para encerrar o processo. Evitamos assim, colocar o código de encerramento no bloco ***try*** e em todos os blocos ***catch***.

No código apresentado em sua pergunta, não há motivos para ter um bloco ***finally***. Então, simplesmente, não o implemente.

Comment: Entendo sua lógica. Acho que me expressei errado. Eu quero finalizar a aplicação dentro do bloco catch. Há alguma maneira ?

Comment: `Environment.Exit(0);`